# How do i get python pptx module to make show the power point file that i am using it to edit

Tags: python, powerpoint

i am working on automating some powerpoint slides in python using pptx.

I would like that when i run the following script, that pptx will not only open, but also display the powerpoint. how do i achieve that?

```
from pptx import Presentation 
from pptx.util import Inches

file = r'S:\file.pptx'

prs = Presentation(file)

prs.show()
```

prs.show() is wrong....is there code that will actually display the ppt?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the library contains that functionality? It's a tool for *creating and editing* presentations, not *displaying* them.

Comment: Hmm, still awaiting the 1st constructive response to the question

Comment: (part of why it doesn't make sense to add display functionality is that it would require the library to become platform-dependent and tied to a widget set; another is simply that there's already an official viewer, made by Microsoft, so there's not a lot of point to building a new one -- certainly not in comparison to how much work it would be)

Comment: Now, if you have Microsoft Office installed and just want to start it from Python, _that's_ easy.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't call "do you have a reason to think you're asking for something that exists?" non-constructive. If you _do_ have such a reason and can provide it, that would give folks doing research to answer your question a place to start.